# iOS. Uploading binary with adMob

Tags: ios, app-store, admob, iad, ads

I am serving both iAds and AdMob in the app. I've put "yes" for question with using IDFA. Received 2 rejections due to having AdSupportFramework in code and then had turned off all of them. But then I received the 3rd rejection with the ask to provide steps to find ads served. I've sent the screenshots with iAds served, as their test banners are always published. But I am not sure, that Apple Review Team can see AdMob test banners. As while developing I used to implement testing device's IDs to code for reviewing AdMob test banners. And how do Apple Review Team can see them? Do you have ideas? Is it necessary to do anything more or provide more information to Review Team for app being approved?

AdMob contract do not allow me to publish real ads now - only after app released

Comment: Did you checked that you can be trusted that you won't send private data to commerce ?

Comment: Do you mean that I am using such type of ads that I do create by myself?

Comment: Where I must check it?